# Javascript variable combination regarding dropdown - probably really simple

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to make a triple dependant dropdown based on arrays. It almost all works. Here's what I have:

```
// Types
var p_arr = new Array();
p_arr[0]="Fire";
p_arr[1]="Police";
p_arr[2]="Medical"; 
p_arr[3]="Accident";

// Brands
var br_a = new Array();
br_a[0]=""; // Select
br_a[1]="Thing|Testing|New"; // relating to p_arr[0], and so on
br_a[2]="Test1|Test2|Test3"; 
br_a[3]="Test4|Test5|Test6";
br_a[4]="Test7|Test8|Test9"; 

// Varieties
var v_a1 = new Array();
v_a1[0]=""; // Select
v_a1[1]="CA|CB|CC"; // relating to br_a[1] first item
v_a1[2]="CD|CF|CG";  // relating to br_a[1] second item, and so on
v_a1[3]="CH|CI|CJ";

// Varieties
var v_a2 = new Array();
v_a2[0]=""; // Select
v_a2[1]="BA|BB|BC"; // relating to br_a[2] first item
v_a2[2]="BD|BF|BG"; // relating to br_a[2] second item, and so on
v_a2[3]="BH|BI|BJ";
v_a2[4]="BK|BL|BM"; 

etc.................
```

When I'm populating my last dropdown, it needs to look at the section for ether v_a1, v_a2, etc. depending on the initial p_arr selection.

I can refer to them like this:

```
var variety_arr = v_a1[selectedBIndex].split("|");

var variety_arr = v_a2[selectedBIndex].split("|");
```

And that works, but I need to automatically select the appropriate group for the last selection, and I don't want to use if/then/else statements.

The variable "selpID" has the value of the number of the selected "p_arr" upon selection. Example, if the first item is selected, it equals "1", if the second, "2", etc.

How can I do this:

```
var variety_arr = v_a{value of selpID}[selectedBIndex].split("|");
```

I've tried brackets, periods, + signs, etc. but I'm stumped (I'm not very good with Javascript). I'm sure there's a simple way of doing this though - how can I add the value of selpID ("1", "2", etc.) to the v_a that doesn't mess up the interpretation of the array?

Comment: Minor note, you can rewrite your array definitions as: `p_arr = [ "Fire", "Police", "Medical", "Accident" ];`. Much shorter right?

Comment: It is shorter, and thank you, but it actually was like that, and I changed it to this because a user will be updating the possible dropdown options - and it's simpler to tell them to separate them with | than with "," - that's why I did it.

Comment: I think I figured this out...


 var vnamebyc = new String("v_a" + selpID);
 var vnamebyc = window[vnamebyc];
 
 var variety_arr = vnamebyc[selectedBrandIndex].split("|");

or:

 var vnamebyc = window["v_a" + selpID];

 var variety_arr = vnamebyc[selectedBrandIndex].split("|");

or simply: 

 var variety_arr = window["v_a" + selpID][selectedBrandIndex].split("|");


the "window[]" evaluates the string with the number added as a variable in JS - similar to the $$var in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You can nest object to arbitrary depth in Javascript, so:

```
var dontCallMeArray = {
    brands: [
        ['red', 'blue', 'dark'],
        'OR|SOME|PERVERSION'.split('|'),                
        ['more', 'nested', 'arrays']
    ],
    types: [
        'Fire', 'Police', 'Medic', 'Coroner' 
    ],
    andSoOn: []
};
```

Comment: sorry, i am not writing query code for this sctructure, because i dont understand what you want to achieve. But, `dontCallMeArray['brands'][0][1]` will return `red`. Quite simple.

Comment: Basically, I'm trying to figure out how to have instead of this - var variety_arr = v_a{value of selpID} something like this - var variety_arr = v_a1, with the "1" placed there from the variable of "selpID"... does that make sense?

Comment: You can use **nested arrays**, so it will be like `v_a[1][selectedBIndex].split('|')` in your case.